# How do i use the actually implementation of $http in angular.js test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I know how to mock the $http module(if module is the correct term) in a test but i want the test to perform the actual http get request. I can't work out how to inject the implementation of $http that is used in the controller.

Controller:

```
function ChecklistController($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
.........
}
```

Comment: Check out $httpBackend: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only valid scenario I can think of for you to do that is to perform end-to-end tests. In such a case, you should use the `passThrough` method of the request handler returned by the `when` method of the `ngMockE2E.$httpBackend` service.

More information on that matter [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.%24httpBackend).

Comment: That looks like it. I spent hours crawling through the documentation trying to find this.